# Combining R plumber and RAppArmor

Tags: r, plumber, apparmor

I simply want to combine the packages plumber and RAppArmor in a way, that users can send code using the plumber-API to a server which is then safely evaluated with the help of profiles in RAppArmor. How can I make the following code work:

```
#* Evaluate the result
#* @post /eval_res
function(func){
  library("RAppArmor")
  data <- cbind(rnorm(100),rnorm(100))
  eval.secure(nrow(data),profile="r-user")
}
```

This code chunk is a simplified version of what is happening later. So far, it seems that any object specified in the function, e.g. data, cannot be passed to eval.secure given the user restrictions in r-user (standard profile of RAppArmor). I even tried allowing full access to /** for r-user by editing the profile, without success. Opening plumber on localhost and using curl with `curl --data "func=function(x){return(nrow(x))}" "http://localhost:8000/eval_res"` to get the result of eval.secure() results in an empty answer `{}`. The same code works without eval.secure() and correctly returns `[100]`. Can someone help me so I understand the problem better or even fix the code?

My current workaround is to save everything to a csv before eval.secure() and then read it within the eval.secure granting access to that folder in the r-user profile, but that is definitely not a convincing solution.

For those of you who are confused about the function: In a later step the option func will contain some code which will the be parsed and evaluated, but for this small example I thought it would only add unnecessary complexity.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```r
library("RAppArmor")

#* Evaluate the result
#* @post /eval_res
function(func){
  data <- cbind(rnorm(100),rnorm(100))
  unix::eval_safe(nrow(data), profile="r-user")
}
```

So

```r
library("RAppArmor")

#* Evaluate the result
#* @post /eval_res
function(func){
  data <- cbind(rnorm(100),rnorm(100))
  unix::eval_safe(eval(parse(text=func)), profile="r-user")
}
```

`eval.secure` just pass all parameters to `unix::eval_safe`. The reason why `eval.secure` does not work is because `eval_safe` expects to find your variables in its `parent.frame()`, which in the case of `eval.secure` is an empty function body.

`eval_safe` use of parent.frame()

```r
function (expr, tmp = tempfile("fork"), std_out = stdout(), std_err = stderr(), 
    timeout = 0, priority = NULL, uid = NULL, gid = NULL, rlimits = NULL, 
    profile = NULL, device = pdf) 
{
    orig_expr <- substitute(expr)
    out <- eval_fork(expr = tryCatch({
        if (length(priority)) 
            setpriority(priority)
        if (length(rlimits)) 
            set_rlimits(rlimits)
        if (length(gid)) 
            setgid(gid)
        if (length(uid)) 
            setuid(uid)
        if (length(profile)) 
            aa_change_profile(profile)
        if (length(device)) 
            options(device = device)
        graphics.off()
        options(menu.graphics = FALSE)
------> serialize(withVisible(eval(orig_expr, parent.frame())), 
            NULL)
    }, error = function(e) {
        old_class <- attr(e, "class")
        structure(e, class = c(old_class, "eval_fork_error"))
    }, finally = substitute(graphics.off())), tmp = tmp, timeout = timeout, 
        std_out = std_out, std_err = std_err)
    if (inherits(out, "eval_fork_error")) 
        base::stop(out)
    res <- unserialize(out)
    if (res$visible) 
        res$value
    else invisible(res$value)
}
```

```r
# parent.frame() in eval_safe when using eval.secure
function (...) 
{
  # nothing here  
  unix::eval_safe(...)
}

# parent.frame() when using eval_safe directly
function(func){
  data <- cbind(rnorm(100),rnorm(100))
  # Your stuff is here
  unix::eval_safe(nrow(data), profile="r-user")
}
```

Comment: That was exactly what I needed. Thank you so much!